# How to debug the "Could not resolve com.google.android:android" error in Anko

Tags: android, kotlin

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
//Anko
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:$anko_version"
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:0.13'

Build error:

Error:Failed to resolve: Could not resolve    
 com.google.android:android:2.3.1.

Required by:  
    project :app > org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:0.13
```

Comment: There probably isn't enough information here to help you. What things about your project can you show readers so they can try to reproduce this error?

Answer (score 1):

I've got same error when installed Android Studio 2.4 Preview. Just make sure, your project-level build.gradle looks like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-3'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1' //Version must be exactly 2.3.1
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: That helped me, thank you. I'm using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1, I had to restart Android Studio and run the gradle sync a couple times more in order for gradle to successfully build. (I also replaced my `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` to `mavenCentral()` , I don't know it that helped.

Comment: @AlexandreG. I'm glad that helped you, consider upgrading to AS 2.3 stable at least ;)

Comment: Ahah that was a typo, I'm running AS 3.0 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:$anko_version"
```

and try again, please.
Or paste the full build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }   to  maven {url "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/"}